# select2 возвращаемые параметры

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Есть `select`:

```
    $(select).select2({
    language: "ru",
    placeholder: "Выберите...",
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "тут_урл_реста",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term,
                page: params.page || 1
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data, page) {
            cache.data = cache.data || {};
            if (!cache.data.__lastPage || cache.data.__lastPage < page) {
                cache.data = {};
            }
            cache.data.__lastPage = page;
            $.each(data.items, function(idx, item) {
                item.text = item.name;
                cache.data[item.id] = item;
            });
            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: data.more
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    templateResult: function(data) {
        return data.text;
    },
});
```

REST сервер возвращает JSON вида:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "название",
            "additional": "данные"
        }
    ],
    "more": false
}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы после того как пользователь выбрал какой-то элемент в списке, в `hidden` поля заносились все три возвращаемых поля: `id`, `name` и `additional`?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вашу проблему, то я бы на вашем месте использовать Data Attribute. Что это такое можно почитать [тут от разработчиков ФФ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). О том как работать с этими атрибутами через jQuery можно почитать [тут](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Если вам надо именно на выбор элемента, то основываясь на [ответ на СО](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615108/trigger-an-action-after-selection-select2) вам надо добавить обработку события `select2-selecting`.

```
$(select).select2({
    // ваш код
}).on("select2-selecting", function(e) { 
    // заполняете поля и вообще делаете всё, что вам надо на выбор элемента
});;
```

Comment: Вопрос в том как сделать чтобы select2 устанавливал эти атрибуты

Comment: А в чем проблема написать код в обработчике ответа, чтобы он устанавливал эти атрибуты?

Comment: Обработчик ответа это где? тотже templateResult вызывается не только при ответе, но и при выводе списка вариантов

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, добавляем еще один обработчик:

```
.on('select change', function(evt, config) {
                var o = $(this).select2('data')[0];
                if(o!=undefined) {
                    console.log(o.additional); // выведет в консоль дополнительные данные
                }
            });
```